# One OnClickHandler with switch/case vs anonymous inner classes

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, theory

I have found that often people use one handler for multiple event sources (for exeampl one OnClickHandler(View v) for several buttons). And then the handler selects a branch depending on the parameter v

For example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mButton1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mButton2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onClick(final View v) {
    if (v == mButton1) {
        title = getString(R.string.action1Title);
        defaultText = getText1();
    } else if ( v == mUriLabel ) {
        title = getString(R.string.action2Title);
        defaultText = getText2;
    }

    // Here some common code
}
```

Here we have two functions. onCreateView just directs all events to single handler. And onClick is handler by it self, which should determine the source of the event and go to one branch or another.

On the other hand we could instantiate in anonymouse inner class which implements onClick. Like this:

```
// In cases, when there is some common part,
// we need additional interface to separate common part and 
// customizable action.
interface ICustomAction {
    void doSomeAction();
}

class BaseHandler implements View.ClickListener {
    ICustomAction mCustomAction;

    // Constructor which receive specific action
    CommonHandler(ICustomAction customAction) {
        mCustomAction = customAction;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClick(final View v) {
        mCustomAction.doSomeAction();
        // Here some common code
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mButton1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mButton1.setOnClickListener(new BaseHandler( new ICustomAction() {
        @Override
        void doSomeAction() {
            title = getString(R.string.action1Title);
            defaultText = getText1();
        }
    }) );

    mButton2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mButton2.setOnClickListener(new BaseHandler( new ICustomAction() {
        @Override
        void doSomeAction() {
            title = getString(R.string.action2Title);
            defaultText = getText2();
        }
    }) );
```

Here we have more complex class communication, but specific differences localized near registering handlers. And we replace switch/case with call to a virtual function (defined in the ICustomAction interface).

Also IDE could simplify representation such anonymous classes and show them like lambda functions

```
mButton2.setOnClickListener(new BaseHandler( () ->{
            title = getString(R.string.action2Title);
            defaultText = getText2();
        } ) );
```

So, registering handler became more compact, but stil contains meaningful differences.

The question is, what reason for using one handler with switch/case statment, and when the approach with anonymouse inner classes is preferable?

Comment: It would make a lot more sense if you made comparisons based on similar implementations. E.g. if you had used `mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener` instead of this home made 'complex' hierarchy

Comment: I want to show example with some common code, which executes always. Direct inheritance of  `View.OnClickListener` leads to code duplication in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous inner classes are more preferable than switch cases.

Consider a case when you have more number of views in your layout and you have set switch case for all of your view in the onClick() method, your switch case have to do several comparisons to reach the correct value.

When it is just two to three view's that will not make a big difference at such times you can use switch case instead if you have lots of view's use anonymous inner class for all the views.

If you think readability is going to be a problem with anonymous inner classes. You can create a **setOnClickListeners()** method to separate all your anonymous inner classes from the onCreate method. Thanks to @Darwind for getting a note on readability.

Comment: This is very opinionated and really depends on your "personal" style. Saying that multiple comparisons can be an issue doesn't really add any value. Yes it creates more comparisons, but it also creates one entrypoint to where `onClick`s are handled. If you use multiple inner anonymous classes, you don't necessarily know where to go and have to look through the code, which can also be an issue when it comes to readability. In the end I would favour readability over "performance".

Comment: @Darwind Performance will matter when you are going to have several onClick events in your view , eg: a calculator. If you are in need of readability you can abstract all your anonymous inner classes into a separate method called setOnClickListeners() which will allow you to have it in a readable form.

Comment: @Darwind, on the other hand, implementation which is based on an anonymous inner class is located directly in the calling the `setOnClickListener`. Someone might find it meaningful and quite readable. But I got your point: it is very opinionated and should be considered from a readability point of view. Thanks for the opinion.